# My script modal is not working

Tags: ajax, laravel, bootstrap-modal, simplemodal

Im trying to test my bootstrap modal in my laravel project but its nothing response.

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
     @section('body')
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <a href="#" class="block padder-v hover" id="btnAgenda">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Block Button</button>
        </a>
    </div>
<div class="modal fade" id="modalAgenda" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="member" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                Agendaaa asd
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $("#btnAgenda").on("click",function(){
        $("#modalAgenda").modal("show");
    });
</script>
```

Why my script its not working ?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Did you add jquery and bootstrap.js?

Comment: 2 Possible Reasons, 1- as suggested by @KótaPéter check jQuery (comes first) and bootstrap.js exist or not, 2- Is your script DOM ready? code in question works properly. http://jsfiddle.net/cemyzefd/ so try with DOM ready http://jsfiddle.net/cemyzefd/1/

Comment: @gerdi when im to inspact manager i get error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: @KótaPéter yes, i sure to add jquery and bootstrap.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## ANSWER - Please mark if correct

From what @Shehary said above.

## index.html

```
<a href="#" class="block padder-v hover" id="btnAgenda">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Block Button</button>
        </a>
<div class="modal fade" id="modalAgenda" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="member" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                Agendaaa asd
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

## jquery

```
$("#btnAgenda").on("click",function(){
    $("#modalAgenda").modal("show");
});
```

2 Possible Reasons, 1- as suggested by @KótaPéter check jQuery (comes first) and bootstrap.js exist or not, 2- Is your script DOM ready? code in question works properly.  so try with DOM ready http://jsfiddle.net/cemyzefd/